# How to create a column which use its own lag value using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data frame

```
c1<- c(1:10)
c2<- c(11:20)
df<- data.frame(c1,c2)

c1  c2
1   11
2   12
3   13
4   14
5   15
6   16
7   17
8   18
9   19
10  20
```

I would like to add a column c3 which is the sum of c3(-1)+c2-c1. For instance,
in the example above the expected result will be:

```
c1  c2  c3
1   11  0
2   12  10
3   13  20
4   14  30
5   15  40
6   16  50
7   17  60
8   18  70
9   19  80
10  20  90
```

Is it possible to perform this operation using dplyr ? I have tried several approaches without success. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good use for `cumsum` - cumulative summation.

```
c3 = lag(cumsum(c2 - c1), default = 0)
```

Don't think of `c3` as c3(-1) + c2 - c1, think of it as c3(n) = sum (from 1 to n - 1) c2(i) - c1(i)

Comment: With `dplyr`: `df %>% mutate(c3 = lag(cumsum(c2 - c1), default = 0))`

Comment: I didn't think to use the cumsum(). Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 3):

This creates column c3. Assuming the first entry is always 0, since there is no preceding element.

```
df$c3 <- df$c2 - df$c1
df[1,"c3"] <- 0
df$c3 <- cumsum(df$c3)
```

output

```
> df
   c1 c2 c3
1   1 11  0
2   2 12 10
3   3 13 20
4   4 14 30
5   5 15 40
6   6 16 50
7   7 17 60
8   8 18 70
9   9 19 80
10 10 20 90
>
```

Comment: This works in this particular case because the difference between `c2` and `c1` is constant - but the way OP phrases the problem you would need to delete the last element and append 0 to the front for it to work generally, not just replace the first element with 0.